# wcf rest design about Quiz System

Tags: rest

I'm designing a rest api about Quiz System, user need to login to do the quiz , there are functions like GetQuiz,GetQuestion.
And other set of api for management of those user and quizs, there are functions like
AddQuestionToQuiz,DeleteQuiz,CreateUser
Now i am confused about how to design it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think in resources and not in method calls. A quiz might be a resource, a user might be a resource, a question might be a resource. All resources support GET, POST,PUT, DELETE.

Sometimes to help me think it through, I think what a website would look like where the resources are HTML and it has links (hypermedia)

HTH

Comment: One interface includes all resources or separate each resource to a interface?

Comment: One .svc file or multiple .svc file is better? And in the website(client), does it need a database to sync with WCF REST(server)'s ?

Comment: These are design decisions and are totally up to you. What you want in the end is URI for each resource. How you construct that is up to you.

Comment: so create one interface which includes all methods? But the methods maybe are not relate to each other, is that ok?

Comment: Yes that's fine. The implementation is completely up to you. When the ASP.NET web api was released the creator of the samples used 2 controllers to implement his services. People said that was a bad Idea, but for him it was his preference. You will have to decide how you want to maintain and dev. this app.